# C# Keeping DLLs with the associated library

Tags: c#, deployment

We have a library built on the back of eldos' Secure Black Box.
We use copy local to ensure that the appropriate runtime DLLs are included.

If we now reference our library in another project with a copy local our library is copied into the bin folder of our main project but the Eldos SBB libraries aren't.  We could reference SBB in the main project but there are no direct calls to SBB so any time the code is refactored the references may be removed as unused.

What is the best way of handling this issue?

Simon

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to put an msbuild script entry into the project properties--> build events --> pre or post build event dialog which would handle copying your Eldos SBB libraries for you.  This way you dont have and explicit reference that might get removed, although someone can remove the script so nothing is 100%.

So your script might look something like this:

```
copy "{path1}EldosSBB.dll" "{path2}EldosSBB.dll"
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Yep - but it isn't really a solution.  We can't be the first people to come up with this issue - surely there is a standard method for doing this?

Simon

Comment: What I have proposed above is, in my opinion, the easiest solution, but certainly you could build something like this into your formal build process if you need to completely remove any dependency from your development environment.